# how to set height of a layout with java in android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

As you can see in the code below, I want to change the height of the answerBar which is a linear layout

```
answerBar.setHeight(55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
answerBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, 50));
```

or:

```
answerBar.getLayoutParams().height = 50;
answerBar.requestLayout();
```